# Store Quantity of product in meters,cm in magento 2.1.12

Tags: magento-2.1, product, quantity

I want to make a website for custom shirt.I want to store quantity in meters,centimeters.It is possible in magento 2.1.12.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is possible.
Actually, there are no units associated with quantity.

You can consider it as 1 quantity as 1kg or 1m or anything else, you just need to adjust your configuration accordingly.

You can set `Qty Uses Decimals` to `yes`, this will allow decimal in quantity box.

You can read more on inventory management at https://docs.magento.com/m2/ee/user_guide/catalog/inventory.html

Also, you can take a look at extension https://www.fmeextensions.com/magento-length-area-volume-pricing-calculator-magento-2.html , I have never used this extension before, I am referring it here by reading the extension description only.